# Incise : Tirets cadratins ou demi-cadratins ?

Tags: typographie, incises

J'ai cherché sur internet quels tirets sont à utiliser pour les incises mais je n'ai trouvé que des réponses vagues ou contradictoires, tout du plus considérant les deux valables.

De ce fait, j'aimerais savoir quel type de tiret est à préconiser pour la chose, ou si les deux sont acceptés : quels sont les différences du point de vue du style et du sens ?

P.-S. : Doit-on dire "Des tirets demi-cadratins" ou "Des tirets demi-cadratin" ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

L'usage varie pour les incises entre le tiret cadratin et le tiret demi-cadratin selon la préférence de la publication, ainsi qu'en atteste cet article [1] et divers usages. Dans la presse, où le texte est souvent rendu en colonnes étroites, le tiret demi-cadratin semble être préféré. C'est aussi le cas pour l'imprimerie nationale.

A ma connaissance le seul cas où le tiret cadratin soit systématiquement utilisé en français est l'indication d'un changement de locuteur dans des répliques de dialogue.

[1] http://www.orthotypographie.fr/volume-II/telegramme-troncation.html#Tiret

PS: je pense qu'on dit "des tirets cadratin" ou "des tirets demi-cadratin", le cadratin étant une unité de longueur égale à la hauteur de la fonte.

Answer (score 0):

J'ai trouvé ça : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiret

Personnellement je pensais qu'il n'y avait que deux longueurs différentes, et j'utilisais le "plus long des deux" pour les incises. Le plus petit me servait de trait d'union, pour des listes, pour les dialogues, etc.